# understanding the ack system for UDP reliability

Tags: networking, network-programming, udp

Firstly, I would like to explain why I am implementing a UDP protocol, I do this for several reasons:

- I have a game project in progress that I will use it.
- I need a network project to deliver.
- I want to learn how it is done, thus having more control.

I'm basing myself on this article:

https://gafferongames.com/post/reliability_ordering_and_congestion_avoidance_over_udp/

but I crashed in the "Acks" part, I can not understand how it works to transmit reliable packets. What I did was:

disregarding the virtual connection id field that I already implemented (I ignore the packages with different id, so the server only accepts packages from an authorized client, and the client only receives packages from the server because it already has its ip to filter it), this is header of the package so far:

```
[sequence]
[ack]
```

the declaration of variances in the client and server script (start with -1, so the count starts at 0 when the first message is sent):

```
var seq_local = -1
var seq_remote = -1
```

Client A sends a message to server B, then the header of the packet would have the field "sequence = 0" and the field "ack = 0", then B would receive the packet and check with an if like this:

```
if seq_recvPacket> seq_remote:
    seq_remote = seq_recvPacket
```

and would send an "ack" message to the client like this:

```
sequence = seq_local_server
ack = seq_remote_server
```

I can not figure out where the ack is being used. If what you check is the "sequence" field.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you can't use TCP? What you're trying to implement here is essentially a worse version of TCP.

Comment: @duskwuff yes, it must be for UDP, it would not be nice to have "picks" in game because of the way TCP does packet forwarding. Read on the link, if you came to this comment is because you still know very little about it. I recommend reading. I was even implementing using websocket, but as said "picks" disrupt the player experience.

Comment: I'm confused by your use of the word "picks". In general, though -- I'm quite familiar with networking, but I'm unconvinced that this approach will be useful for most applications (yes, including games). Keep in mind that, even if you provide reliability with the selective-ACK mechanism described in that post, you're still missing a lot of TCP features, like arbitrary-length packets…

Comment: here it explains the situation https://gafferongames.com/post/udp_vs_tcp/, I also plan to implement, but only if necessary, I'm still not sure of the size of the packages, if they are all too small, I will not implement fragmentation to My case.

Comment: "_I will not implement fragmentation to My case._" You don't implement fragmentation, that happens automatically to IPv4 packets by routers in the path if the MTU shrinks below the size of your IPv4 packet. You can prevent fragmentation by setting the DF flag in the IPv4 packet header, but then any oversize IPv4 packets get dropped, and an ICMP message sent back to the source.

Comment: @RonMaupin I know this, but they are fragmented, but when I said I would not implement it would be that I would not treat the fragments if they were fragmented, otherwise they would not, because I do not believe my packages will not exceed the MTU. These are short messages.

Comment: The IP fragmentation and reassembly are transparent to your application. Fragmentation happens in the routers in the path, and the IP module reassembles them before they are sent up to UDP or TCP. Your application is blissfully unaware if fragmentation happened or not.

Comment: @RonMaupin The ip protocol regroups the fragments and delivery to the UDP and TCP transport layer protocols?

Comment: Yes. IP fragmentation happens in the IPv4 module, and TCP or UDP have no knowledge of it. TCP will segment a stream of data, and it will reassemble the segments into streams, but that has nothing to do with fragmentation.

Comment: @RonMaupin but it has to have the reassembly, I expressed myself badly, it is from her that I am speaking that I will not implement if my packages are not large enough to exceed the MTU.

Comment: TCP itself handles segmentation, which is transparent to your application.

Comment: but I'm talking about UDP. TCP is out of the question.